# [Magento 1.9.2]Customer email not saved

Tags: magento-1.9, email, sales-order

I'm having an issue with customer email not being saved in order details.
It happens when not registered customer makes an order, whether he chooses to register or buy as a guest.

That is how "Account information" section in order view looks like:

```
Customer Name: Guest
Email (that field is empty)
Customer Group: General
```

And that is how it should look like:

```
Customer Name: Firstname Lastname
Email: j596669@trbvm.com
Customer Group: NOT LOGGED IN
```

Weird thing about that is that I "solved" this problem yesterday by changing:
Customers > Customer Configuration > Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group –  from YES to NO.

After changing that it worked just fine, but today it doesn't work again neither on *Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group* enabled nor disabled.

Do you happen to have any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Solved by disabling persistent shopping cart

Comment: Please add it as an answer and accept it so it doesn't add upto the queue of un-answered questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by disabling persistent shopping cart